# composer network deploy, command not found

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am doing this tutorial: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-deploy-interact-extend-local-blockchain-network-with-hyperledger-composer/index.html

And here I have to do `composer network deploy` but this is what I get:

```
composer network <subcommand>

Composer network command

Commands:
  composer network download [options]  Downloads a business network from the Hyperledger Fabric, does not undeploy
  composer network install [options]   Installs a business network archive to Hyperledger Fabric
  composer network list [options]      List the contents of a business network
  composer network loglevel [options]  Change the logging level of a business network
  composer network ping [options]      Test a connection to a business network
  composer network reset [options]     Resets a business network
  composer network start [options]     Starts a specific version of a business network that is already installed to Hyperledger Fabric
  composer network upgrade [options]   Upgrades to a specific version of a business network that is already installed to Hyperledger Fabric

Options:
  --help         Show help  [boolean]
  -v, --version  Show version number  [boolean]

Incorrect command. Please see the list of commands above, or enter "composer network --help".
```

So my Question here is if this command got changed to `composer network install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the command has been changed to composer network install. You can follow [documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial) of composer for the commands.